# Excel VBA Text To Column

Tags: excel, vba

This is what I currently have:

```
H101    John Doe    Jane Doe    Jack Doe    
H102    John Smith  Jane Smith  Katie Smith Jack Smith
```

And here is what I want:

```
H101    John Doe
H101    Jane Doe
H101    Jack Doe
H102    John Smith
H102    Jane Smith
H102    Katie Smith
H102    Jack Smith
```

Obviously I want to do this on a bigger scale. The number of columns is between 1 & 6, so I cant limit it that way. I was able to get a script that allows me to put each individual on one row. However, I am having a hard time getting the first column to copy over to each row.

```
Sub ToOneColumn()
Dim i As Long, k As Long, j As Integer
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Columns(2).Insert
i = 0
k = 1
While Not IsEmpty(Cells(k, 3))
    j = 3
    While Not IsEmpty(Cells(k, j))
        i = i + 1
        Cells(i, 1) = Cells(k, 1) //CODE IN QUESTION
        Cells(i, 2) = Cells(k, j)
        Cells(k, j).Clear
        j = j + 1
    Wend
    k = k + 1
Wend
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Like I said, it was working fine to get everyone each on their own row, but can't figure out how to get that first column. It seems like it should be so simple, but it's bugging me. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're writing over your data in column 1.
You create a new column for the names but not for the first column, though it depends on exactly what your original format is.

Try this:

```
Sub ToOneColumn()
Dim i As Long, k As Long, j As Integer
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Columns(2).Insert
Columns(2).Insert
i = 0
k = 1
While Not IsEmpty(Cells(k, 3))
    j = 4
    While Not IsEmpty(Cells(k, j))
        i = i + 1
        Cells(i, 2) = Cells(k, 1) //CODE IN QUESTION
        Cells(i, 3) = Cells(k, j)
        Cells(k, j).Clear
        j = j + 1
    Wend
    k = k + 1
Wend
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Then delete all but the two created columns.

Comment: @Pat: Yes, I agree with Lance Roberts. It looks like k should be 2, but hard to tell without testing. That is why I made my recommendations about messy code. In addition to my answer, you need to specify better variable names. For instance, what are i, j, k? Why make me figure it out from looking at the code.